# In triangle ABC, diameter and radius of circumcircle meet BC at Q and M. Prove $\frac{[AQC]}{[MTC]}=\left(\frac{\sin B}{\cos C}\right)^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In triangle ABC, the height from A cuts the circumcircle at T. The diameter of the circle that passes through A and the radius OT cut the side BC at Q and M, respectively. Demonstrate that
$$\frac{[AQC]}{[MTC]}=\bigg(\frac{\sin B}{\cos C}\bigg)^2$$
I draw this figure 
[image]
And working with the triangles I found that
$$[AQC]=R^2\cos2B\sin2B\\
[MTC]=4R^2\sin2B\sin^3B$$
But, how can I find the relation of this areas with the angle C?
Can someone help me?

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Note

\begin{align}
& \angle BCT = \angle BAT = 90-\angle B \\
& \angle CAQ = \angle ACO = \frac12(180 - \angle AOC) = 90-\angle B\\
\end{align}

which leads to $ \angle BCT = \angle CAQ$, $\angle CTO = \angle OCT= \angle ACB
$ and, hence, similar triangles CMT and CAQ. Thus,

$$\frac{[AQC]}{[MTC]}= \left( \frac { AC}{CT} \right)^2=
\left( \frac { \sin \angle CTA}{\sin \angle CAT} \right)^2=
\left(\frac{\sin B}{\sin(90- C)}\right)^2
= \left(\frac{\sin B}{\cos C}\right)^2
$$